# como obtengo ultimo id insertado en mysql con php7

Tags: mysql, mysqli, php7

tengo un pequeño problema, trato de insertar un dato en  mysql, pero no logro obtener el id del registro insertado con php, este es mi codigo:

```js
$query="INSERT INTO clientes (nombre,apellido) values ('cami','agu');SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
$query="SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
printf($resultado);
```

con esa sentencia directamente en phpmyadmin si inserta y trae el id, con ese codigo desde php solo inserta, mas no me devuelve el ultimo id.

Comment: No necesitas ejecutar el SELECT justo despues del INSERT. Si la tabla clientes usa un autoincremental, puedes emplear el método mysqli_insert_id como se describe aquí https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ("Nuevo registro con el id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

Comment: Buenas, Frank, se parece mucho lo que has copiado a esta página del manual de PHP  https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php Indica la fuente y añade alguna explicación. Además, ten en cuenta que el OP no está empleando orientación a objetos.

Comment: Hola, ya lo intente con la documentacion y no funciona incluso tienen mas abajito el ejemplo con el query como lo ejemplifique: mysqli_query, pero no trae el ultimo id, no logro comprender